# Splitting CSV file into text files

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a CSV file of the form:

```
1,frog
2,truck
3,truck
4,deer
5,automobile
```

and so on, for about 50 000 entries. I want to create 50 000 separate .txt files named with the number before the comma and containing the word after the comma, like so:

```
1.txt  contains: frog
2.txt  contains: truck
3.txt  contains: truck
4.txt  contains: deer
5.txt  contains: automobile
```

and so on.

This is the script I've written so far, but it does not work properly:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder=/home/data/cifar10

for file in $(find "$folder" -type f -iname "*.csv")
do
    name=$(basename "$file" .txt)

while read -r tag line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >"$tag".txt
done <"$file"
rm "$file"

done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your inner loop:

```
while read -r tag line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line" > "$tag".txt
done < "$file"
```

You need to set `IFS` to `,` so that tag and line are parsed correctly:

```
while IFS=, read -r tag line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" > "$tag".txt
done < "$file"
```

You can use `shopt -s globstar` instead of `find`, with Bash 4.0+.  This will be immune to word splitting and globbing, unlike plain `find`:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in /home/data/cifar10/**/*.csv; do
  while IFS=, read -r tag line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" > "$tag".txt
  done < "$file"
done
```

Note that the name set through `name=$(basename "$file" .txt)` statement is not being used in your code.

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

An awk alternative:

```
awk -F, '{print $2 > $1 ".txt"}' file.csv
```

Comment: This throws an error for me: `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {print $2 > $1 >>>  ".txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Comment: I followed up about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617558/how-to-split-a-csv-file-into-multiple-txt-files-using-awk-or-other-command-line?noredirect=1#comment124837657_70617558) and the solution is to use `awk -F, '{print $2 > ($1 ".txt")}' file.csv`

Comment: An unparenthesized expression on the rigght side of output (or input) redirection is undefined behavior, hence the error message from some awks. It needs to be `> ($1 ".txt")` instead of `> $1 ".txt"`. That will still run into a "too many open files error" though depending on how many output files are being produced, which awk you're using, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {print $1".txt  contains: "$2}' file

1.txt  contains: frog
2.txt  contains: truck
3.txt  contains: truck
4.txt  contains: deer
5.txt  contains: automobile
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it just prints that text to the terminal. How do I actually create seperate .txt files?