# How to split a CSV file into multiple txt files using awk (or other command line tool)?

Tags: awk, command-line, terminal

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
1,apple
2,orange
3,orange
4,pear
5,banana
```

The CSV file has thousands of rows.

Now I want to split it into thousands of separate .txt files.

Each .txt file should be named with the number before the comma and the contents of the .txt file should contain the word after the comma, like so:

```
1.txt  contains: apple
2.txt  contains: orange
3.txt  contains: orange
4.txt  contains: pear
5.txt  contains: banana
```

and so on.

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348185/splitting-csv-file-into-text-files) asking how to do this using a bash script, but I want to do it using the command line (awk or similar) and the current answers on that question using awk do not work correctly.

Comment: This "awk -F, '{print $2 > $1 ".txt"}'  file.csv " command from the similar question is working perfectly, I tried with your given "sample" input file, and it gives desired output file(with filename) and its contents.

Comment: @c_bfx That's strange, because when I try it gives this error `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {print $2 > $1 >>>  ".txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`. I'm on a Mac. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Try: `awk -F, '{print $2 > ($1 ".txt")}' file.csv`

Comment: That worked! Thank you! If you add it as an answer I will accept it as the solution. Or if you don't want to I will do it for you.

Comment: Are those numbers in the first column unique or could you, for example, have 2 rows with number `1` in the first column? Does your CSV have a header line (if so, please show it in your example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print $2 > $1 ".txt"
```

is an undefined behavior as per POSIX `awk` so different AWKs make different choices of what `print > a b` should behave.

You should group string concatenation in a single expression after redirection operator like this:

```sh
awk -F, '{print $2 > ($1 ".txt")}' file.csv
```

I believe the reason of that is `>` operator taking precedence over sting concatenation thus making `$2 > $1`, a single command and treating `.txt` afterwards as a syntax error.

---

On non-gnu AWKs, `>` operator opens a new file every time, `awk` will start throwing error due to limitations of open file handles if input is more than a few lines. You should use this command to close file handle every time after use:

```sh
awk -F, '{fn = $1 ".txt"; print $2 > fn; close(fn)}' file.csv
```

Comment: This works, but it stops once it hits record number 2557 and throws this error `awk: can't open file 2557.txt
 input record number 2557, file file.csv
 source line number 1`. It doesn't have anything to do with the text in the cell at 2557 because if I delete that cell and re-run it still gets stuck at 2557 (which now has different text in that cell). Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: try this: `awk -F, '{fn = $1 ".txt"; print $2 > fn; close(fn)}' file.csv`

Comment: It's not just older versions of awk that need the parens, it's simply undefined behavior per POSIX so different awks make different choices of what `print > foo bar` should mean. I've seen the "too many open files" error happen with less than 20 output files so it's not just huge numbers of output files that can have the problem, I wouldn't rely on NOT having that problem unless you have less than 15 output files.

Comment: Thanks so much Ed for your insight. I will edit explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using this `awk` you can get the five files:

```
awk -F, '/^[[:digit:]]+/ {close(output); output=$1} {$1=$1".txt";$2=" contains: " $2;print > output}' file
```

- content and names of each file:

```
$ cat 1                                                                        
1.txt  contains: apple
$ cat 2
2.txt  contains: orange
$ cat 3
3.txt  contains: orange
$ cat 4
4.txt  contains: pear
$ cat 5
5.txt  contains: banana
```

You can see these posts:

- [How to split a YAML into multiple files with a proper name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404550/how-to-split-a-yaml-into-multiple-files-with-a-proper-name)
- [Split Large Text file into smaller files parts according to file content](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684790/split-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-parts-according-to-file-content)
- [Possible to do with Awk or Sed? Splitting big file into smaller files. Lines between two markers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684753/possible-to-do-with-awk-or-sed-splitting-big-file-into-smaller-files-lines-bet)

Comment: This is throwing the error `awk: null file name in print or getline
 input record number 1, file file2.csv
 source line number 1`

Comment: Perhaps I write at the end the name `file`, and you the name `file.csv`...

Comment: My csv file is named `file2.csv`. When I use `awk -F, '/^[[:digit:]]+/ {close(ouput); output=$1} {$1=$1".txt";$2=" contains: " $2;print > output}' file2.csv` it gives the error `awk: null file name in print or getline
 input record number 1, file file2.csv
 source line number 1`. And when I try `awk -F, '/^[[:digit:]]+/ {close(ouput); output=$1} {$1=$1".txt";$2=" contains: " $2;print > output}' file2` it gives the error
 `awk: can't open file file2
 source line number 1`.

Comment: Ok. This is my `awk` version: 
`GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)` What's happening or why the error you mention? Honestly, I don't know.

Comment: The OP might have a header line not shown in the example that doesn't start with a digit or they might be running a non-POSIX awk (e.g. `nawk`) that doesn't support character classes like `[[:digit:]]` and so `output` is not populated the first time `print` is called.

Comment: btw you have a typo - `close(ouput)` should be `close(output)` (with a `t` in the middle).

Comment: Oh, yes: `close(output)`, edited.